# Captura de alteração de elemento em carrosel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte `carousel` feito em `bootstrap`

Previous
                  
                  
                    
                    Next

E tenho o seguinte `js` feito com o objetivo de pegar o `title` da imagem que estiver `ativa` na tela no momento:

```
 setInterval( ()=> {
        $('#carousel-exemplo div.active').each(function() {
           var hr = this.getAttribute('title');              
           var select = $('img', this).attr('title');
           $('#showTitle').text(select);          

    });
},1)
```

Com esse código, pego o título e jogo em um `parágrafo` como mostra o exemplo abaixo em execução:

```js
   setInterval( ()=> {
   $('#carousel-exemplo div.active').each(function() {
               var hr = this.getAttribute('title');              
      var select = $('img', this).attr('title');
      $('#showTitle').text(select);    
  
  });
 },1)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div id="carousel-exemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="http://maxtitanium.com.br/images/share/200x200-2015-05-14-06-42-12.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo!">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://www.whatsbroadcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/WhatsApp-1-200x200.png" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo 2!">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="http://1001cursos.online/files/sites/3755/2017/09/logo-200-x-200.png" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo 3!">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-exemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-exemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div> 
    <p id="showTitle">aqui: </p> 
   </div>    
  </div>
 </div> 
  
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

O código está funcionando normalmente com o objetivo que eu preciso, mas creio que com o `setInterval` não seja o modo mais semântico de realizar essa função.

Minha pergunta é, há outro modo de capturar o momento em que a imagem foi alterada e capturar o seu atributo `title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você não precisa do setIterval basta fazer o bind com o evento de slid. Uma vez que você está pegando a informação do item com a classe `.active` essa informação está sempre disponível para o item atual.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Exibe o título com o elemento active inicial
  setTituloActive();

  $('#carousel-exemplo').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    //atualiza o valor com o item ativo no momento.
    setTituloActive();
  });
});

function setTituloActive() {
  var elemento = $('#carousel-exemplo div.active');
  var select = $('img', elemento).attr('title');
  $('#showTitle').text(select);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div id="carousel-exemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="http://maxtitanium.com.br/images/share/200x200-2015-05-14-06-42-12.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo!">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://www.whatsbroadcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/WhatsApp-1-200x200.png" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo 2!">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="http://1001cursos.online/files/sites/3755/2017/09/logo-200-x-200.png" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo 3!">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-exemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-exemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <p id="showTitle">aqui: </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Outra opção e muito mais simples, é incluir o título junto aos itens... o que também manteria o efeito de slide para eles.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div id="carousel-exemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="http://maxtitanium.com.br/images/share/200x200-2015-05-14-06-42-12.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo!">
             <p>Titulo de exemplo!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://www.whatsbroadcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/WhatsApp-1-200x200.png" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo 2!">
            <p>Titulo de exemplo 2!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="http://1001cursos.online/files/sites/3755/2017/09/logo-200-x-200.png" class="img-fluid" alt="exemplo" title="Titulo de exemplo 3!">
            <p>Titulo de exemplo 3!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-exemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-exemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Leandro, a primeira imagem não está puxando o título, apenas quando é realizado o slide.

Comment: O `slide.bs.carousel` é o evento de transição de imagem? É o evento disparado na hora da troca das imagens?

Comment: Isso, editei para exibir o valor inicial também usando a mesma função que atualiza no evento de slide

Comment: O problema é que a segunda imagem vem com  título da primeira e a terceira com o título da segunda,e ao passar por todas as imagens a primeira imagem fica com o título da terceira.

Comment: Entendi, no seu caso precisa do evento slid e não o slide (mudei no código), porém esse só dispara ao fim da animação. Outra alternativa seria simplesmente escrever esses valores como parte do template de cada item.

Comment: Leandro, obrigado! Como eu implementaria os valores nos itens?

Comment: Leandro, obrigado pela resposta, mas no meu caso, a  segunda opção não me serve, pois irei exibir o título em outra `div`, mas a primeira opção me serviu. Obrigado!